# How can I use PHP preg_match for an e-mail that contains a period?

Tags: php, preg-match, email-validation

I am trying to create a user validation form to check the e-mail and also run it against my database. However, if there is an e-mail, such as "my.name@domain.com", it will put it into the database anyway, even if it is a duplicate entry.

```
if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9z])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
       //regular expression for email validation
        $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
    } else {
         $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
    }
```

How would I change preg_match to look for the period in there? BTW, all users registering for the site will have a period in their e-mail (it is only for a select group of people that have the same e-mail format).

Comment: You should be using [`filter_var()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead of a regex

Comment: Please don't use regexes to validate email addresses.  PHP has [built in email validation](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate) and there are [*awesome* external libraries](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/) that catch more RFC-caused edge cases.  Also, the only *real* way to validate an email address is to send mail to it.  Use format validation for typo protection at best.

Comment: Got it. I'll make that change. I am authorizing users by sending an e-mail to it, but this is a check to make sure I am able to do that first. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your minimum goal is making sure that there's at least one period in the local part of the email address, because *your specific use case* requires this.  We can probably bit a bit naive and use

```
/.*\..*@/
```

as the main check.  This searches for zero or more of anything, one period, then zero or more of anything, then an at sign.  This will successfully make sure that there's at least one dot in there, where it matters.  Consider changing the `*`s to `+`s unless you want the string `.@` to pass this check.  I'm not sure where you expect the period, and can't remember off the top of my head whether or not periods are allowed as the first or last characters in the local part.

Combine this with a call to `filter_var($_POST['e-mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to *actually* check the full formatting of the address.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` php filter instead of `reqex`

```
if (filter_var($_POST['e-mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //Valid Email
} else {
    //Invalid Email
}
```